# Matrix transformation for linear state-space systems

Tags: optimization, control-theory, optimal-control

In http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-241j-dynamic-systems-and-control-spring-2011/lecture-notes/MIT6_241JS11_lec12.pdf on pages 11-12 it is said:

For a stable and strictly causal state-space system $H(s)=C(sI-A)^{-1}B$ the following statements are equivalent:

1. $(I-\frac{1}{\gamma^2}H^T(-s)H(s))^{-1}$ has no poles on the imaginary axis (with $H^T(-s)=-B^T(sI+A)^{-T}C^T$).
2. $M_\gamma =
   \left( \begin{matrix}
   A &  \frac{1}{\gamma}BB^{T} \\
   -\frac{1}{\gamma}C^{T}C  &  -A^T \\
   \end{matrix} \right)
   $  has no purely imaginary eigenvalues.

But how can I show it? It seems to be a simple matrix transformation, but I have no idea on how to do it.

Something like:

$det(sI-M_\gamma)=det(sI-A)det(sI+A^T)+det(\frac{1}{\gamma^{2}}BB^{T})det(C^{T}C)=0$
$\implies 1+det(\frac{1}{\gamma^2}BB^T(sI+A)^{-T}C^TC(sI-A)^{-1})=0$

And then I have to reach somehow:

$I+\frac{1}{\gamma^2}B^T(sI+A)^{-T}C^TC(sI-A)^{-1}B=(I-H^T(-s)H(s))=0$

1. Note: I am not  a student there. But I try to understand the mathematics, because it is necessary for another problem.
2. I have the feeling that it might be $(I-\frac{1}{\gamma^2}H(s)H^T(-s))^{-1}$ and not $(I-\frac{1}{\gamma^2}H^T(-s)H(s))^{-1}$. Because the Matlab commands

   A=[1 2;3 4];B=[3;0];C=[2 0];D=0;H=ss(A,B,C,D);HT=ss(-A',-C',B',0);(1+HT*H)^-1
   results in something that looks like 
   the eigenvalues of $
   \left( \begin{matrix}
   -A^T &  -\frac{1}{\gamma}C^{T}C \\
    -\frac{1}{\gamma}BB^{T} &  A \\
   \end{matrix} \right)
   $.

Comment: $A^{-T}$ is new to me. I had a look at the slides and for my level it left out far too much. I would try to get the list of references for that course and look there. BTW I found a nice article on determinants of block matrices: http://www.ee.iisc.ernet.in/new/people/faculty/prasantg/downloads/blocks.pdf

Comment: @mmw Thank you first of all. $A^{-T}$ is nothing special. It is just the transposed inverse matrix of A. So you do the inverse first and transpose then.

Comment: On 2 at least you appear to have misunderstood the claim. The slides claim that the TF is bounded by $\gamma$ in the $H_\infty$ norm iff $M_{\gamma}$ has no purely imaginary eigenvalues. The conditions on the transfer function are just basic properties that you probably need, but your proof should start out by assuming $H_\infty$ boundedness and then you argue about the nature of the eigenvalues.

Comment: @ALB: Thank you very much for your comment. The step from $H_\infty$ norm to $(I-\frac{1}{\gamma^2}H^T(-s)H(s))^{-1}$ is pretty much clear. 
It can be done by Neumann-series of matrices. But the step "Putting together the realizations, and eliminating the internal variables ..." from the slides is unclear. It is exactly the relationship as shown above.